# Insufficient pods in Amazon EKS Fargate

Tags: kubernetes, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

When I try to install metrics server on EKS Fargate cluster, it is throwing error:

> 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient pods.

Following instructions from here to install metrics server: http://arun-gupta.github.io/hpa-app-metrics/

Can someone tell me why this error is throwing up?

update:
when i make additional deployment, it is allocating new pods and working fine. but it is showing this error when metrics are installed by following instructions in the above link

Comment: The same issue to me ! Is the problem solved?

Comment: not resolved. seems people didn't get my question clearly

Comment: What kind of node type are you using in your EKS cluster? m5.2xlarge as suggested in the guide?

Comment: i didn't configure nodes explicitly. eks fargate assigning pods config as per requested pod configuration

Comment: Ok Rajeev, I asked you because the node type could limit the number of pods you can launch because of the available ENIs and IPs addresses.

Comment: @Rajeev Then, how do you create your Fargate stuff? How do your Fargate profile looks like? Please, can you expand your question and provide more information that maybe help in understand the problem?

Comment: pls see this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html

Comment: Last time I ran into this it was because of volumes. The helm chart is trying to create a disk-backed volume on the Fargate node here https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/9a737ef3d42d4cb286edb120c7a499ee8fbfa7d4/stable/metrics-server/templates/metrics-server-deployment.yaml#L71

Fargate does not support mounting the local file system. If you edit the deployment and remove the lines referencing volumes, does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the AWS Fargate docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate.html)

Fargate profiles support specifying subnets from VPC secondary CIDR blocks. You may want to specify a secondary CIDR block because there are a limited number of IP addresses available in a subnet. **As a result, there are a limited number of pods that can be created in the cluster**. Using different subnets for pods allows you to increase the number of available IP addresses. For more information, see [Adding IPv4 CIDR blocks to a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-resize).

Comment: how to increase size of the node in fargate? i never configured nodes explicitly in the cluster

Comment: The same isscue to me. I think the number of IP is enough, 8K*3

Comment: This is not the correct answer, this could be one of the reason for the issue faced. I checked the number of available IPs and subnet has around 400 IPs available still the pods are in pending state with error - "insufficient pods"